# Adding links to simple_form hints?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, hint

Is there a way to have a link inside a hint from an specific input within a `simple_form` form?

For example-  "Forgot your password?" in passwords' input hint.

This way some styling could be avoided to attach the link to the input box.

May be a stupid question but I can't figure out how to do it :/

Thanks in advance.

Edit (This syntax is wrong, but hope it gives the idea on what I am trying to say, specifically in line 3):

```
=simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
    =f.input :email, placeholder: "me@example.com"                             
    =f.input :password, hint: { link_to "Forgot your password?", new_password_path(resource_name) }
```

Comment: This question is unclear and not understood as what being asked here. Other than that there is no code or what else you tried.

Comment: I recommend to attach a snapshot or post a code whenever you find difficulty so that it will be easy for others to answer.

Comment: @SaurabhJain Hope this last editing helps

Answer (score 17, accepted):

All you need is interpolation.

```
<%= f.input :password, hint: "#{link_to 'Forgot your password?', new_password_path(resource_name)}" %>
```

This will insert your code within the hint. In this case a forgotten password link.

Comment: Wow, thank you, sometimes the easiest stuff gets to be the hardest. I've been stuck with this for a while, honestly... Thank you!

Comment: No problem, good to hear I've saved you some time. Now you can focus on the harder stuff once again.

Comment: For me just that didn't worked, I needed to pass the string to raw like said here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/issues/965

Comment: I had to slap a .html_safe onto it like this `<%= f.input :password, hint: "#{link_to 'Forgot your password?', new_password_path(resource_name)}".html_safe %>`